# parse number/currency data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a data set with monetary values like "$28.2 mn" and "€ 19 bn". For formatting I need to turn this generated content:

```
<p>$28.2 mn</p>
```

Into this:

```
<p><span class="currency">$</span>28.2 <span class="denomination">mn</span></p>
```

I need to do this with Javascript/jQuery after the page has loaded.

The data may or may not have spaces after the currency symbol. There may or may not be spaces between the number and the denomination. The numbers sometimes are whole and sometimes have a a decimal value.

I have played with some regex but this is beyond my skill set. If anyone has any thoughts it would be much appreciated.

Comment: [`([^\d.,]+)\s*([\d.,]+)\s*([^\d.,]+)`](http://rubular.com/r/ERZERMcDaU). This simply assumes numbers are anything that have digits, dots and commas. Anything coming before it is the currency and anything coming after it is the denomination. This also allows for optional spaces between these groups. This won't work if there are spaces in the number, dots in the currency symbol, etc.

Comment: With a small sanity check - only one decimal point <code>([^\d.,]+)\s*([\d]+[\.{1}]?[\d]+)\s*([^\d.,]+)</code>

Comment: @Satyajit Your regex is wrong. You can't use quantifiers (eg: `{1}`) inside a character class. Besides, many countries (most of Europe and South America) use `.` as a thousands separator instead of the comma, eg: 100.000 = 100 thousand.

Comment: @NullUserException the regex is not wrong. Check this http://rubular.com/r/OBQL7OLjVD. Try putting in two periods for the decimal and it won't match while a single period will match. OTOH I do agree with you that EU countries use , as the thousands separator.

Comment: @Satyajit It *is* wrong. Try replacing the dot with a curly brace `{` and you'll see [it still matches](http://rubular.com/r/PUFc1IT5I3). Quantifiers **don't** work in character classes. `[\.{1}]?` means "optionally match one of these characters: `.{}1`" What you really wanted was: `[.]?`, which means "optionally match (one or zero times) a dot"

Comment: The regex expressions here seem to be close. Does anyone know how they would be implemented with jQuery to create the classes? Is there a way to have it work if there is no currency symbol in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to combine the regex expression left by NullUserException with the other answer submitted to come up with the solution:

```
$('p').html(function(i, c){
    var cur = $.trim( c );
    cur = cur.replace(/([^\d.,]+)\s*([\d.,]+)\s*([^\d.,]+)/g,
        '<span class="currency">$1</span> $2 <span class="denomination">$3</span>');
    return cur;
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hje94/